# How to add a new column to an existed partitioned table in dolphindb?

Tags: database, partition, dolphindb

How to add a new column to an existed partitioned table in dolphindb?

I create a partitioned table and insert some data in it, the code is:

```
ID=1..6
x=1..6\5
t1=table(ID, x)
db=database("dfs://rangedb", RANGE, 1 4 7)
pt = db.createPartitionedTable(t1, `pt, `ID)
pt.append!(t1);
```

Now, I want to add two columns into this table. For an example: the columns are ["price", "qty"], and the data types are [DOUBLE, INT]. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It can be added through the [addColumn](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/CommandsReferences/addColumn.html) function, an example is as follows:

```py
pt = load Table( "dfs://rangedb" , "pt" )
add Column(pt,[ "price" , "qty" ],[DOUBLE, INT]) ;
```